# Is this OpenGL lighting working as intended?

Tags: opengl

I have setup a very basic fragment shader containing a directional light. I am trying to light a single quad using this directional light and everything seems to be working as intended but I have one question: *Should both sides of this flat quad be affected by the directional light?*

When rotating the camera around I notice that the back of the quad is as bright as the front. Should this be happening or should only **one** side of the quad be lit?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because the back face of your quad is the "same quad" as the front face. They have the same normal, so the lighting gives the same result. If you don't want this, two solution:

1. Enable back face culling. You won't see the back face anymore. If you need to see something, draw another quad but oriented in the other direction.
2. In your fragment shader, test [gl_FrontFacing](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_FrontFacing.xhtml). If it's false, negate the normal. It can be done without branch with something like this:

   normal = gl_FrontFacing ? normal : -normal;

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying in the first paragraph. Let's say the light source is somewhere in front. Since the normal is the same, the back side should in fact look darker, since the normal points away from the light when the back side is visible (i.e. oriented towards the viewer). So the two sides would only be equally bright if two-sided lighting is implemented, as you describe in item 2.

Comment: BTW, the `?` operator implies a branch. It's basically just a shortcut for an `if` statement.

Comment: Let's say the light source is in front and the normal points toward it. The quad is lit. That's the same for the back face and the front face, they are the same thing. They're lit because the normal points toward the light. If you put the camera behind the quad, it doesn't change its normal, it stays towards the light. Is it clearer?

Comment: The operator ? is slightly different from a branch, especially in shaders. It translates in an instruction that does the conditionnal assignment (instead of a jump), so in practice it doesn't have the drawbacks of a branch. If you use an if, maybe the compiler will change it into a conditionnal assignment, or maybe not (especially if you have other code in the block). Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Oh, I think I do understand what you mean now. This is true if you keep the light stationary relative to the plane, and only move the camera. Which is of course possible. I guess it depends heavily on the application and use case. I find it much more common to keep the light stationary relative to the camera, and move the object around. Or, looking at it differently, moving the light with the camera.

Comment: The `?` operator in GLSL is defined to only evaluate one of the two expressions. So conceptually, it needs a branch to skip the evaluation of the other expression. If the expressions have no side effects, it could of course evaluate both expressions regardless. But the same is true for an `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, but it's easier to add side effects in the block of an if than in the single expressions of the ternary operator. And you're never completely sure that a glsl compiler will transform an if into a conditionnal assignment, even if there's no side effect. So in simple cases like this IMO there is no point using an if.